# Spring Integration code throws exception on upgrading to Spring 3.2

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-3

Below Spring Integration 3.0 code is working successfully in Spring 3.0.

But, on upgrading to Spring 3.2, it throws below 2 exceptions:

```
org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Unable to access property 'messages' through getter

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid method parameter for messages: was expecting a single payload.

<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
    query="select ..."
    channel="inp" data-source="dataSource"
    <int:poller fixed-rate="2000">
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Above query returns one or more rows and result is assigned to List of Service Activator

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="inp" ref="FileService" output-channel="resp" />

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inp", outputChannel = "resp")
public List<?> process(List<?> ) {
    ...
}
```

Getting below exception in Spring 3.2.

```
10:15:44.556 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel] preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Unable to access property 'messages' through getter][Headers={timestamp=1402409744556, id=a5143a74-7da4-d745-bda5-2a74ce102491}]
10:15:44.556 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] (inner bean)#d72200 received message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Unable to access property 'messages' through getter][Headers={timestamp=1402409744556, id=a5143a74-7da4-d745-bda5-2a74ce102491}]
10:15:44.559 ERROR [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Unable to access property 'messages' through getter
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:67)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:199)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:141)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:273)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:268)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Unable to access property 'messages' through getter
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectivePropertyAccessor$OptimalPropertyAccessor.read(ReflectivePropertyAccessor.java:614)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:202)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:78)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getArguments(MethodReference.java:147)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueRef(MethodReference.java:66)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:63)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:103)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:73)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectivePropertyAccessor$OptimalPropertyAccessor.read(ReflectivePropertyAccessor.java:610)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid method parameter for messages: was expecting a single payload.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$ParametersWrapper.getMessages(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:788)
    ... 48 more
```

EDIT: payload and header as per the logs

```
[Payload=[{NID=1241430 , CTR=0   , FLAG=01, UPDATETIME=2013-08-12 07:42:35.137}, {NID=1241430 , CTR=001 , FLAG=01, UPDATETIME=2013-08-12 07:42:35.457}]][Headers={timestamp=1402472659515, id=a08ec480-1356-001b-e6f7-0511b9ecf6d6}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding `method="process"` to the `<service-activator>` should fix the issue.

Assume your `FileService` has several methods and for framework it is difficult to determine which one to use for each case, if they aren't consist with Messaging rules.

**UPDATE**
Actually the `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` returns `List<?>` independently of rows count. Looks like your `process(List<?> )` should be more specific for List's generic type, because your payload is a `List<Object>`, not `List<Message<?>>`.

There are two cases when `MessagingMethodInvokerHelper` build expression for `messages` evaluation context root object:

```
if (annotationType.equals(Payloads.class)) {
    sb.append("messages.![payload");


else if ((parameterTypeDescriptor.isAssignableTo(messageListTypeDescriptor) || parameterTypeDescriptor
                                .isAssignableTo(messageArrayTypeDescriptor))) {
    sb.append("messages");
```

I think your issue is around the seocnd one. There something has been changed in Spring for `TypeDescriptor` since 3.2.

Comment: same exception on adding method="process" in <service-activator>. Spring is able to recognize the process method. My payload and header as per the logs: [Payload=[{NID=1241430 , CTR=0   , FLAG=01, UPDATETIME=2013-08-12 07:42:35.137}, {NID=1241430 , CTR=001 , FLAG=01, UPDATETIME=2013-08-12 07:42:35.457}]][Headers={timestamp=1402472659515, id=a08ec480-1356-001b-e6f7-0511b9ecf6d6}]

Comment: Updated answer. Actually your payload is a `List` anyway - `{...}`

Comment: yes, I checked with multiple rows and the same exception. I have updated my comments and question accordingly. I got some clue with your updated answer. will update you on this. thank you.

Comment: It's resolved by changing List<?> to Message<List<?>> msg and then msg.getPayload() to get the list